# How can I group curves by similar shape with different data size length for each data array?

Tags: python

If you have a set of points that each yield a curve, and the size of the points describing the curve varies between each curve (say 30 x,y points for curve one, 25 curve 2, 15 curve 3) what is the correct way to optimally group the curves? I am just looking for the best method to do this.

Comment: Since it is a curve and it is created using some points, I might think that such curves are polynomial with the order of the number of points - 1.
If that is correct, you might try comparing Taylor series, or even simpler, you might cluster them based on the difference for the union of all the points. It's then up to you to decide your definition of "similar".

Comment: Thanks I will try both.

Comment: Beware, you might find useful measuring the differences as squared, otherwise big errors with different signs would compensate.